# Using select2 and binding values to dynamically created select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am creating select boxes dynamically using AddMoreDrugsToBilling method. And filling it with options by calling showDrugs in the onclick event of the selectbox. Problem is that when I make the selectbox as select2 (searchable select box), the onclick event of the select box is no longer getting called and thus values are not getting loaded to the select box. How to make the dynamically created selectboxes as select2 and also fill it with values?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    debugger;
    $(".selectDrugs").select2();
 })

$(function() {            
        getDrugs();            
        AddMoreDrugsToBilling();            
});

function AddMoreDrugsToBilling() {
        //debugger;            
   if ($("#tbl_Drugs tbody").length > 0) {
      $("<tr id=" + tblDrugsCount + "><td><select class='selectDrugs' width='250px' id='txt_Drugs" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' onchange='onChangeDrugText(this," + tblDrugsCount + ");' onclick='showDrugs(" + tblDrugsCount + ");' /></td><td><select id='txt_Batches" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' onchange='onChangeBatchText(this," + tblDrugsCount + ");' /></td><td><label id='lbl_ExpiryDate" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' /></td><td><label id='lbl_UnitPrice" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' type='text'/></td><td><label id='lbl_AvlQty" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' type='text'/></td><td><input class='form-control input-100px' onkeyup='CheckMaxQuantity(" + (tblDrugsCount) + ");' id='txt_Qty" + (tblDrugsCount) + "'   type='text'/></td><td><label id='lbl_Amount" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' ></label></td><td><img src='../Images/delete.gif' id='img_delete" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' title='Delete' onclick='DeleteDrugItemrow(this);'/></td></tr>").appendTo("#tbl_Drugs tbody");
     }
    else {
      $("<tbody><tr id=" + tblDrugsCount + "><td><select class='selectDrugs' width='250px' id='txt_Drugs" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' onchange='onChangeDrugText(this," + tblDrugsCount + ");' onclick='showDrugs(" + tblDrugsCount + ");' /></td><td><select id='txt_Batches" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' onchange='onChangeBatchText(this," + tblDrugsCount + ");' /></td><td><label id='lbl_ExpiryDate" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' /></td><td><label id='lbl_UnitPrice" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' type='text'/></td><td><label id='lbl_AvlQty" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' type='text'/></td><td><input class='form-control input-100px' onkeyup='CheckMaxQuantity(" + (tblDrugsCount) + ");' id='txt_Qty" + (tblDrugsCount) + "'  type='text'/></td><td><label id='lbl_Amount" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' ></label></td> <td><img src='../Images/delete.gif' id='img_delete" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' title='Delete' onclick='DeleteDrugItemrow(this);'/></td></tr></tbody>").appendTo("#tbl_Drugs");
   }               
   tblDrugsCount++;            
 }

var drugsData = [];
    function getDrugs() {
        // debugger;

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            url: 'NewPharmacyOrder.aspx/FillDrugs',
            success: function(data) {
                //debugger;
                var resultDrugItems = data.d;
                for (i = 0; i < resultDrugItems.length; i++) {
                    var item1 = resultDrugItems[i];
                    drugsData.push({ "DrugName": item1.DrugName, "DrugId": item1.DrugId});
                }
            }
        });           

    }

function showDrugs(id) {
        debugger;

        var txtDrugsList = $("#txt_Drugs" + id);

        var txtDrugsListCtrl = document.getElementById("txt_Drugs" + id);
        //alert(txtDrugsListCtrl.length);
        if (txtDrugsListCtrl.length == 0) {
            //if ($(txtDrugsList).length == 1) {
            //            if($("#txt_Drugs"+id) option).length)
            txtDrugsList.empty();
            $("#txt_Drugs" + id).get(0).options[0] = new Option("select drug", "-1");

            $.each(drugsData, function(index, item) {
                // debugger;
                var option1 = new Option(item.DrugName, item.DrugId);
                //option1.setAttribute('data-availablebatches', item.AvailableBatches);
                txtDrugsList.append(option1);
            });
            // }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

You are thinking that `getDrugs();` calling will pull data and then control will go to `AddMoreDrugsToBilling();` which is not happening because here you are making an ajax request which is sent asynchronously.

- `Async:False` = Codes **paused**. (Other codes are **waiting** for this to finish..)
- `Async:True` = Codes **continued**. (Nothing gets paused. Other codes are **not waiting**.)

As simple as this.

So to make sure that data is loaded you can simply move the function call `AddMoreDrugsToBilling();` to the `success` callback instead of calling it just after `getDrugs();`

Below is the updated code:

```
$(function(){
  debugger;
  $(".selectDrugs").select2();
  getDrugs();  
});

function AddMoreDrugsToBilling(){
  //debugger;            
  if($("#tbl_Drugs tbody").length > 0){
    $("<tr id=" + tblDrugsCount + "><td><select class='selectDrugs' width='250px' id='txt_Drugs" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' onchange='onChangeDrugText(this," + tblDrugsCount + ");' onclick='showDrugs(" + tblDrugsCount + ");' /></td><td><select id='txt_Batches" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' onchange='onChangeBatchText(this," + tblDrugsCount + ");' /></td><td><label id='lbl_ExpiryDate" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' /></td><td><label id='lbl_UnitPrice" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' type='text'/></td><td><label id='lbl_AvlQty" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' type='text'/></td><td><input class='form-control input-100px' onkeyup='CheckMaxQuantity(" + (tblDrugsCount) + ");' id='txt_Qty" + (tblDrugsCount) + "'   type='text'/></td><td><label id='lbl_Amount" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' ></label></td><td><img src='../Images/delete.gif' id='img_delete" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' title='Delete' onclick='DeleteDrugItemrow(this);'/></td></tr>").appendTo("#tbl_Drugs tbody");
  }else{
    $("<tbody><tr id=" + tblDrugsCount + "><td><select class='selectDrugs' width='250px' id='txt_Drugs" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' onchange='onChangeDrugText(this," + tblDrugsCount + ");' onclick='showDrugs(" + tblDrugsCount + ");' /></td><td><select id='txt_Batches" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' onchange='onChangeBatchText(this," + tblDrugsCount + ");' /></td><td><label id='lbl_ExpiryDate" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' /></td><td><label id='lbl_UnitPrice" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' type='text'/></td><td><label id='lbl_AvlQty" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' type='text'/></td><td><input class='form-control input-100px' onkeyup='CheckMaxQuantity(" + (tblDrugsCount) + ");' id='txt_Qty" + (tblDrugsCount) + "'  type='text'/></td><td><label id='lbl_Amount" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' ></label></td> <td><img src='../Images/delete.gif' id='img_delete" + (tblDrugsCount) + "' title='Delete' onclick='DeleteDrugItemrow(this);'/></td></tr></tbody>").appendTo("#tbl_Drugs");
  }
  tblDrugsCount++;
}

var drugsData = [];
function getDrugs(){
  // debugger;
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    data: {},
    url: 'NewPharmacyOrder.aspx/FillDrugs',
    success: function(data){
      //debugger;
      var resultDrugItems = data.d;
      for(i = 0; i < resultDrugItems.length; i++){
        var item1 = resultDrugItems[i];
        drugsData.push({"DrugName": item1.DrugName,
          "DrugId": item1.DrugId});
      }
      AddMoreDrugsToBilling(); /* here you can call this to appened data */
    }
  });
}

function showDrugs(id){
  debugger;

  var txtDrugsList = $("#txt_Drugs" + id);
  var txtDrugsListCtrl = document.getElementById("txt_Drugs" + id);
  //alert(txtDrugsListCtrl.length);
  if(txtDrugsListCtrl.length == 0){
    //if ($(txtDrugsList).length == 1) {
    //            if($("#txt_Drugs"+id) option).length)
    txtDrugsList.empty();
    $("#txt_Drugs" + id).get(0).options[0] = new Option("select drug", "-1");

    $.each(drugsData, function(index, item){
      // debugger;
      var option1 = new Option(item.DrugName, item.DrugId);
      //option1.setAttribute('data-availablebatches', item.AvailableBatches);
      txtDrugsList.append(option1);
    });
    // }
  }
}
```